# How can I convert this SQL code to equivalent pandas code involving a lag function?

Tags: python, pandas, lag

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a patient's ID and hospital admit time. I want to filter out the rows where a patient's admission occurs within 30 days of the previous admission (but include the first admission). With SQL I was able to do this using the `lag` function:

```
case
  -- mark the first hospital adm 
      when dense_rank() over (partition by adm.subject_id order by adm.admittime) = 1 then true
  -- mark subsequent hospital adms if its been atleast a month since previous admission.
      when round((cast(extract(epoch from adm.admittime - lag(adm.admittime, 1) over (partition by
        adm.subject_id order by adm.admittime))/(60*60*24) as numeric)), 2) >= 30.0 then true
      else false end as include_adm
```

How do I do this with pandas? Essentially, I want to filter out one row of patient ID 30 from the following dataframe:

```
id  admit_time
0   30  2018-10-03
1   30  2018-10-29
2   13  2017-11-01
3   13  2018-02-27
```

to get

```
id  admit_time
0   30  2018-10-03
1   13  2017-11-01
2   13  2018-02-27
```

as the patient's second admission falls within 30 days of the first admission. But both the admissions of patient 13 are kept as the difference between the admission dates is more than 30 days.

What I've shown above is an example dataframe. The real dataframe consists of more columns and rows. More specifically, one of the column is a clinical note for that patient taken at a specified time. Thus, there are a lot of duplicate information in the rows **expect for the clinical note**. For example, the above dataframe:

```
id  admit_time  note
0   30  2018-10-03  note_content1
1   30  2018-10-03  note_content2
2   30  2018-10-29  note_content1
3   30  2018-10-29  note_content2
4   13  2017-11-01  note_content1
5   13  2018-02-27  note_content2
6   13  2018-02-27  note_content2
```

should result in the following dataframe after filteration:

```
id  admit_time  note
0   30  2018-10-03  note_content1
1   30  2018-10-03  note_content2
2   13  2017-11-01  note_content1
3   13  2018-02-27  note_content1
4   13  2018-02-27  note_content2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff) to calculate the difference of each `admit_time` per `id` group on the sorted dataframe and select any rows with `NaT` difference (i.e. first row per group) or difference > 30 days. Finally we remove the auxiliary column `delta`:

```
df['delta'] = df.sort_values(['id', 'admit_time']).groupby('id')['admit_time'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())
df = df[df.delta.isna() | (df.delta >= pd.Timedelta(days=30))].drop(columns='delta')
```

Output:

```
   id admit_time
0  30 2018-10-03
2  13 2017-11-01
3  13 2018-02-27
```

**Update for the amended question:**

Group by `['id','note']` instead of just `'id'`:

```
df['delta'] = df.sort_values(['id', 'admit_time']).groupby(['id','note'])['admit_time'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())
df = df[df.delta.isna() | (df.delta >= pd.Timedelta(days=30))].drop(columns='delta')
```

Result:

```
   id admit_time           note
0  30 2018-10-03  note_content1
1  30 2018-10-03  note_content2
4  13 2017-11-01  note_content1
5  13 2018-02-27  note_content1
6  13 2018-02-27  note_content2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That works, however, there is a problem. I didn't specify that there could be duplicate rows with almost all information same except for 1 specific column. This will lead to a delta of zero days for a single admission, but this needs to be preserved. I've edited my original question to include this extra information.

Comment: IIUC you'd need to group by `['id', 'note']` instead of just `'id'`.

Comment: There's a typo in your example data: the note for row 5 should be  note_content1 instead of note_content2, shouldn't it?

Comment: I believe I corrected it. In your original code, I added an extra OR condition saying ```df['delta'] == pd.Timedelta(days=0)``` along with the already present conditions and it seems to work. Your thoughts?

Comment: You don't need this extra condition if you use diff as in my current answer. It was in the very frist version where I used put a time delta of 0 for the first row. In the current code I leave the NaT values and filter on them - it's simpler and more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df=df.sort_values(by=["id", "admit_time"]) #in case your data is not sorted
>>> df_2=df.join(df.groupby("id").min(), on="id", how="left", rsuffix="_min")
>>> df_2["time_diff"]=np.where(df_2["id"]==df_2["id"].shift(), (pd.to_datetime(df_2["admit_time"])-pd.to_datetime(df_2["admit_time"].shift())).astype('timedelta64[D]'), 0)
>>> df_2
   admit_time  id admit_time_min  time_diff
0  2018-10-03  30     2018-10-03        0.0
1  2018-10-29  30     2018-10-03       26.0
2  2017-11-01  13     2017-11-01        0.0
3  2018-02-27  13     2017-11-01      118.0
>>> df_2[(df_2["admit_time"]==df_2["admit_time_min"])  | (df_2["time_diff"]>=30)]
   admit_time  id admit_time_min  time_diff
0  2018-10-03  30     2018-10-03        0.0
2  2017-11-01  13     2017-11-01        0.0
3  2018-02-27  13     2017-11-01      118.0
```

2 caveats:

(1) you need to sort your data first by `id, admit_time`

(2) I didn't find equivalent to `dense_rank` - so it's doing regular `rank`